# Can a wordpress admin see my failed Login attempts?

Tags: wp-admin, password

First of all I am a careful (maybe paranoid) guy. I tried to login into a WordPress account a few days ago and didn´t notice it was the "Admin" login. I even noticed that I could login via Twitch ... but that was too late!

Back to my story. If I try to login via "www.xyz.com/wp-login.php" -> Is it possible that the actual Admin will get my Data (Username/Mail/Password)?

Comment: yes it is possible like it is possible with any site no matter what is its platform. downvoted as there is no "wordpress development" question here

Answer (score 1):

> First of all I am a careful (maybe paranoid) guy. I tried to login into a Wordpress account few days ago and didn´t noticed it was the "Admin" login. I even notice that I can login via Twitch ... but that was too late!

If it's not your account you should notify them! If you can get in who else might be in there doing bad things?

> Back to my story. If I try to login via "www.xyz.com/wp-login.php" -> Is it possible that the actuall Admin will get my Data (Username/Mail/Password)?

If it's a standard install, no, but from what you've said it isn't. So possibly yes, if code has been installed, there's no way of knowing without reading the code or looking at which plugins are installed.

Thankfull, you follow the advice to use strong passwords, and to **never reuse passwords**.

Comment: The loginpage looks like this: https://codex.wordpress.org/images/6/60/login_form.png

Comment: There really is no way to give you a definitive yes or no answer here or from just looking at the site. You'd need to read the PHP code of the site. You should change your password anyway and notify the people who run the site that you managed to login as an admin when you shouldn't have been able to